# Phonegap android navigation bar is not hiding even after the keyboard is closed

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I have an app in phonegap that runs on ios and android platforms.

In my app I have main navigation menu at the bottom like this:

[image]

But my problem is when the keyboard is opened, my navigation menu hides behind the navigation bar and won't go down until i have to close and resume the app.

[image]

I tried the different solutions from google but nothing seems to work, every time keyboard open my navigation menu hides behind navigation bar.

Comment: when keyboard open navigation bar showed up. when i close the keyboard the navigation bar should be closed too but it didn't it stays and hide my navigation menu.

Comment: Any progress with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it may solve your problem.

```
var hideKeyboard = function() {  document.activeElement.blur();  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');  for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {   inputs[i].blur();  } };
```

For more detail you can check the link

http://uihacker.blogspot.in/2011/10/javascript-hide-ios-soft-keyboard.html

Comment: i have problem in android. u gave me ios solution. btw i try ur code its not working.